# Domain Forward Refused to display 'http://webhosting.luminate.com/forward.html' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, web

I deployed my web app on AWS and used Yahoo domain forward with masked url to redirect to my home page. I am getting this error "Refused to display 'http://webhosting.luminate.com/forward.html' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'" in my console. Any tips? 
when I switch yahoo domain forward with unmasked, the error disappears.[original error from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAQ5d.png)

Answer (score 1):

The `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` is actually set by the server you're requesting from. This prevents other sites to embed their content. [See more about X-Frame-Options on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).